# Error: Transformer_test() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I run the code below, I get the error

```
Transformer_test() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

```
class Transformer(tf.keras.Model):
    """
    Complete transformer with an Encoder and a Decoder
    """
    def __init__(self, num_layers, embedding_dim, num_heads, fully_connected_dim, input_vocab_size, 
               target_vocab_size, max_positional_encoding_input,
               max_positional_encoding_target, dropout_rate=0.1, layernorm_eps=1e-6):
        super(Transformer, self).__init__()
 
        self.encoder = Encoder(num_layers=num_layers,
                               embedding_dim=embedding_dim,
                               num_heads=num_heads,
                               fully_connected_dim=fully_connected_dim,
                               input_vocab_size=input_vocab_size,
                               maximum_position_encoding=max_positional_encoding_input,
                               dropout_rate=dropout_rate,
                               layernorm_eps=layernorm_eps)
 
        self.decoder = Decoder(num_layers=num_layers, 
                               embedding_dim=embedding_dim,
                               num_heads=num_heads,
                               fully_connected_dim=fully_connected_dim,
                               target_vocab_size=target_vocab_size, 
                               maximum_position_encoding=max_positional_encoding_target,
                               dropout_rate=dropout_rate,
                               layernorm_eps=layernorm_eps)
 
        self.final_layer = Dense(target_vocab_size, activation='softmax')
    
    def call(self, input_sentence, output_sentence, training, enc_padding_mask, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask):
        """
        Forward pass for the entire Transformer
        Arguments:
            input_sentence -- Tensor of shape (batch_size, input_seq_len, fully_connected_dim)
                              An array of the indexes of the words in the input sentence
            output_sentence -- Tensor of shape (batch_size, target_seq_len, fully_connected_dim)
                              An array of the indexes of the words in the output sentence
            training -- Boolean, set to true to activate
                        the training mode for dropout layers
            enc_padding_mask -- Boolean mask to ensure that the padding is not 
                    treated as part of the input
            look_ahead_mask -- Boolean mask for the target_input
            dec_padding_mask -- Boolean mask for the second multihead attention layer
        Returns:
            final_output -- Describe me
            attention_weights - Dictionary of tensors containing all the attention weights for the decoder
                                each of shape Tensor of shape (batch_size, num_heads, target_seq_len, input_seq_len)
        
        """
        # START CODE HERE
        # call self.encoder with the appropriate arguments to get the encoder output
        enc_output = self.encoder(input_sentence, training, enc_padding_mask)  # (batch_size, inp_seq_len, fully_connected_dim)
        
        # call self.decoder with the appropriate arguments to get the decoder output
        # dec_output.shape == (batch_size, tar_seq_len, fully_connected_dim)
        dec_output, attention_weights = self.decoder(output_sentence, enc_output, training, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask)
        #(tar, enc_output, training, look_ahead_mask, dec_padding_mask)
        # pass decoder output through a linear layer and softmax (~2 lines)
        final_output = self.final_layer(dec_output) # (batch_size, tar_seq_len, target_vocab_size)
        # END CODE HERE
 
        return final_output, attention_weights

# UNIT TEST
Transformer_test(Transformer, create_look_ahead_mask, create_padding_mask)
```

Comment: The error is about transformer_test and you did not include this function in the question.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, Thanks for help on pointing it out...